# Cannot read output of ./a.out

Tags: terminal, compile-vim

My current keybinding for compiling cpp files is:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F2> :!g++ -g %<CR>:!./a.out<CR>
```

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, vim escapes to the shell and a.out executes well uptil taking input. But, it does not wait for output and returns back to the editor. This never happened earlier when I typed the command manually, vim used to wait for me to read the output and then I got a line saying: "Press ENTER or type command to continue."

[Update]
I changed the command to:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F2> :!g++ -g %<CR>:!./a.out
```

Now when I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, it finally writes `:!./a.out` below and I manually press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This time it actually waits for me in the terminal. Why is this happening?

Try reproducing by using both the keybindings this one and the former.

Comment: Your command seems to work for me; that being said: in general, I avoid putting any other Vim commands on the same line after a shell command in `:![cmd]` (especially in mappings) because I'm not really smart enough to remember all the escaping rules and such, and sometimes it behaves unexpected. You can use a single shell command with `nnoremap <F2> :!g++ -g % && ./a.out<CR>`.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow figured out what was going on.

The problem was due to a trailing whitespace at the very end of the keybinding. That was acting as extra key to escape back from the terminal. Removing it resolved the issue.